# Newbie issue with url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I have few questions and I need your advice. So I'm building mini CMS system where users submit content and I construct an url from their content's headline and id e.g. **"74/my-name-is-john-stewart"** and insert it to DB besides original context. When I retrieve data with GET method **deal?url=74/my-name-is-john-stewart** I wonder how to convert that link to **deal/74/my-name-is-john-stewart** format like in Stackoverflow. And I have doubts if it's a proper way, cause when user deletes id number part, different content is loaded, but url's title part stays the same. I'm afraid , maybe it might cause some SEO problems in the future?

Comment: It's the other way around. You need to convert the `74/my-name-is-john-stewart` to `deal?url=74/my-name-is-john-stewart` using something like: `RewriteRule .* deal?url=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules in `/deal/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /deal/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(deal)\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?q=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```